# ScrollView won't size correctly in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, interface-builder

I'm trying to add a scrollview to my ViewController so that I can zoom and then scroll, but the SV won't size correctly inside the view. First, I have a xib with a standard view for my VC. Then I add a scrollView and pin it to that view. I pin a new view to that SV (it's content view), and then pin all my subviews inside that content view. However, despite the fact that everything is pinned to the first view, the scrollview expands beyond these pins. You can see the orange dotted line in this image that shows how the scrollView will expand. How can I get this scrollView to stay inside the phone's screen?

[image]

Comment: Those dotted orange lines in IB are there to indicate that the frames represented in your XIB don't match the current constraint rules.  See that yellow warning indicator to the right of the "View" text in your view hierarchy tree?  Click that to view and resolve current conflicts.  Then you might have a better idea as to what's happening with your UIScrollview constraints.

Comment: Yes, of course. But if I update it, the frames spread out HUGE despite the fact that I have pinned them to the first view.

Comment: Right, but there must be a reason for it.  You might want to check the constants on all your constraints.  If you "pin" an attribute when the frame is offset, IB could potentially set a large constant on the resulting constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Add an equal-widths constraint from the scrollview's *content* view to the *top-level view*. This will disable horizontal scrolling, and force the content size to be what you expect.

Comment: That's a great idea. I'll definitely give that a try.